# Connect to remote oracle database using php 5.6

Tags: php, oracle, apache, oracle11g, php-5.6

I have two machines:

1. Windows 7 x64
2. Windows server 2012 R2 x64

In the first machine I installed:

- Apache 2.4 TS VC11
- PHP 5.6.19 TS VCC
- [php_oci8-2.0.8-5.6-ts-vc11-x64](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/2.0.8/)

I connect to local/remote oracle databases without problem.

The second machine is a fresh server installation, it does not have local oracle dabatases, nothing. The idea is to connect to a remote oracle instace. So I made the same installation (apache and php with same versions as first machine), but the first error I found was that the oci8_11g extension is not loaded. My question is, do I need to install some "driver" or "client" for oracle in this server? The apache instance and php work as expected except with error mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using windows, right? In that case, you need to install Oracle Driver (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html). "Basic" package should do.

Also uncomment this line from `php.ini`: `extension=php_oci8.dll`, or `extension=php_oci811g.dll`, or `extension=php_oci812c.dll`, depending on which oracle version you are using.

Comment: Thank you.  I am tearing right now.  I will come back with results

Comment: I came back with success results. Thank you